# Using sed to show exact location of file

Tags: linux, sed

My command is :

```
[root@my /]# grep -lr --include=*version.php "$wp_version"/home/draka/www/
/home/draka/www/wp-content/version.php
/home/draka/www/wp-content/themes/version.php
/home/draka/www/wp-includes/version.php
```

And i use sed to find the specific line :

```
[root@my /]# grep -lr --include=*version.php "$wp_version" /home/draka/www/ | xargs sed -n '7p'
$wp_version = '3.5';
```

The file version of every folder are different :

1. /home/draka/www/wp-content/version.php = $wp_version = '3.5.1';
2. /home/draka/www/wp-content/themes/version.php = $wp_version = '3.5';
3. /home/draka/www/wp-includes/version.php = $wp_version = '1.5';

My question is, how can i combine that 2 output? The output that i want maybe something like :

```
/home/draka/www/wp-content/version.php = $wp_version = '3.5.1';
```

or

```
/home/draka/www/wp-content/version.php -> $wp_version = '3.5.1';
```

Your prompt reply is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: I think you can remove the `-l` flag so that the matches are printed by grep itself

Comment: If i remove the `-l` it will not show the matches file =)

Comment: If you remove the `-l` you *should* get output that looks like `/home/draka/www/wp-content/version.php:$wp_version = '3.5.1';`.

Comment: I've already removed the `-l` flag and my output is :

`sed: can't read /home/draka/www/wp-content/version.php:: No such file or directory`

Comment: No, remove the `-l` from the *first* command you showed and it will do what you want.  You don't need `sed` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omitting `-l`, like `grep -r --include=*version.php wp_version /home/draka/www/`, will do it. See also *man grep*:

> ```
> -H, --with-filename
>    Print the file name for each match.  This is the default when there is more
>    than one file to search.
> ```

Comment: Yeah! This is what i want. My command is :  

`[root@my /]# grep -r --include=*version.php "wp_version = '" /home/draka/www/
    /home/draka/www/wp-content/version.php:$wp_version = '3.5';
    /home/draka/www/wp-content/themes/version.php:$wp_version = '1.5';
    /home/draka/www/wp-includes/version.php:$wp_version = '3.5.1';
`
I just play around what kind of *pattern* i want, in my case is `"wp_version = '"`

Thank you guys!