# Using grep command to find Joomla version 1.6

Tags: linux, grep

In my previous question ([Using sed to show exact location of file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16359410/1983854)), i am succeed to find wordpress version and show the file path using grep command :

```
grep -r --include=*version.php "wp_version = '" /home/draka/www/
```

And today i am trying to find joomla version using same method and add `\` to find multiple words. My command :

```
grep -r --include=*version.php "RELEASE =\|DEV_LEVEL =" /home/draka/www/
```

And the output :

```
/home/draka/www/joomla1.7/includes/version.php: public $RELEASE = '1.7';
/home/draka/www/joomla1.7/includes/version.php: public $DEV_LEVEL = '5';
/home/draka/www/joomla2.5/libraries/cms/version/version.php:    public $RELEASE = '2.5';
/home/draka/www/joomla2.5/libraries/cms/version/version.php:    public $DEV_LEVEL = '11';
```

But for joomla 1.6, it not show the output using same command. Can anybody tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They changed the spacing in joomla 1.7, in your grep there is only one space between `RELEASE` and `=`, whereas in 1.6 they aligned the equal signs, so there are a different number of spaces. Use the following grep to take arbitrary spacing into account:

```
grep -r --include=*version.php "RELEASE[[:space:]]*=\|DEV_LEVEL[[:space:]]*=" /home/draka/www/
```

Comment: Thank you @Gerhard Burger. You solved my problem. For conclusion, using `[:space:]` it will read how many spacing on what pattern we want,am i correct?

Comment: You're welcome :) You are almost correct, in a single pair of brackets you can choose which characters to match, eg `[ab]` will match a single a or b. Then the character that follows, determines how many times it should match, eg `*` will match 0 or more times. So `[ab]*` will match any combination of consecutive a's and b's The `[:space:]` denotes all possible whitespace characters, so `[[:space:]]*` will match any combination of whitespace (also matches if there is no whitespace, because `*` matches 0 or more times). For more info see the grep man page: http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep